# Sending user location to whatsapp and facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, google-maps, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to send user location to facebook and whatsapp from my app by UIActivityViewController.

```
- (IBAction)shareUserLocation:(id)sender {

    shareArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=%f,%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude]],nil];
    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareArray applicationActivities:nil];
    controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Its working but opening the location in apple maps.
Is there a way I can open the location in Google maps.

P.S- I have not tried whatsApp i have only tested for facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a Google Maps URL in your Google Maps iOS app, you can use `comgooglemapsurl://maps.google.com/?q=%f,%f`. If you want to show it in browser, you can do `https://maps.google.com/?q=%f,%f`.

Sample code:

```
-(void)testURL:(CLLocation*)location {

    NSArray *shareArray;
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
       shareArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemapsurl://maps.google.com/?q=%f,%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude]],nil];

    } else {
        shareArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/?q=%f,%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude]],nil];

    }

    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareArray applicationActivities:nil];
    controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```